# How to export methods to avoid writing import * as ...?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

Consider I have a file like this:

```
// Utilities.ts

export const appDateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

export const isNullOrWhitespace = (value: string | null | undefined): boolean => {
    if (value == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!value) {
        return true;
    }
    return value.trim().length <= 0;
};

export const formatDate = (date: Date): string => {
    return moment(date).format(appDateFormat);
};
```

From the outside, for example in a React Native component, I import those methods like this:

```
import * as Utilities from "../../services/Utilities";
```

And I invoke the methods like this: `if (Utilities.isNullOrWhitespace(inputName)) ...`

Another way to import is:

```
import {isNullOrWhitespace} from "../../services/Utilities";
```

And the usage is: `if (isNullOrWhitespace(inputName)) ...`.

Personally, I prefer the first case because I like to see the "class" that exposes those methods, if the name is right (not this case), in my opinion it's a more expressive way to invoke methods.

---

My problems is that I always have to define the `Utilities` file and its methods to be able to write `import * as Utilities` which I don't like because, for example, WebStorm or Visual Studio Code intellisense never help me to add it automatically to my imports: I have to write it manually.

For example intellisense helps me instantly if I have an object like this:

```
// Colors.ts

export default {
    primaryColor: '#cc0001',
    accentColor: '#6db584',
}
```

...by automatically importing `import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";`

---

Is there a way to define the `Utilities` file and methods in order to avoid having to write the import section manually, in some way to help intellisense understand how to auto import the methods?

Comment: Just export a single `Utilities` object and stop exporting individual functions and variables. It's basic: `const Utilities = {isNullOrWhiteSpace: () => ... etc. }`. Then just export it

Comment: @slebetman This will prevent tree shaking though.

Comment: `Utilities` is not a class, it's a namespace, or "module object". And it contains plain functions, not "methods".

Comment: @Bergi I don't see why it should. Before ES6 modules this was how modules work because commonjs can only export one thing. Unless newer bundlers completely ignore lessons learned from older bundlers. I'd consider it a bug in the tree shaking logic instead of a problem with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually pretty much answered your own question with your `export default` example:

```js
// Utilities.ts

export const appDateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

export const isNullOrWhitespace = (value: string | null | undefined): boolean => {
    if (value == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!value) {
        return true;
    }
    return value.trim().length <= 0;
};

export const formatDate = (date: Date): string => {
    return moment(date).format(appDateFormat);
};

export default {
    appDateFormat,
    isNullOrWhitespace,
    formatDate
}
```